# Magento phpunit assertion - assertEquals(true, false)

Tags: php, magento, phpunit, assert, assertions

I am trying to use EcomDev_PHPUnit package for unit testing on Magento, and I had some issues in configuring it. I have posted the issue and the solution that worked for me here -

[**MAGENTO.stackexchange.com**-Pointers to write unit test cases using EcomDev_PHPUnit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6069/pointers-to-write-unit-test-cases-using-ecomdev-phpunit)

Now, I have a really generic question,

```
class Webservice_Clientservice_Test_Model_ClientserviceimplTest extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case{

    public function testBasicFunctionality(){
        try{
            //Mage::log("testBasicFunctinality");
            $this->assertSame(true,false);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

}
```

When I run this test using

```
phpunit --group Webservice_Clientservice
```

I get the following,

```
phpunit --group Webservice_Clientservice
PHPUnit 3.7.22 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /mnt/www/dev.magento.com/phpunit.xml.dist

..

Time: 3 seconds, Memory: 22.25Mb

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

I was expecting the assert would fail and the test case would eventually fail...How come is it passing? Something is really wrong...True can't be equal to false :( And, also the test case runs twice? I don't know why....

Comment: did you figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Where is `@group` annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap a test with a `try catch` block your test will not fail.

```
// failing test
public function testFail() {
    $this->assertSame(true, false);
}

// successful test
public function testSuccess() {
    try {
        $this->assertSame(true, false);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "go on";
    }
}
```

If you'd like to force a test to fail you can use `fail` method:

```
public function testForceFail() {
    $this->fail('Failed Yeah');
}
```